# How to set width and height attributes on SVG <use> element?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to change the `width`/`height` of a `<use>` element, which [according to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElementWidthAttribute) and various docs **should** be possible as long as the element it inherits from does not have these properties set.

Unfortunately, it seems that a `<use>` element **will not display at all** if it references a `<rect>` which does not have `width` and `height` attributes set. Can anyone explain this?

If you instead inherit from an element which can not have a `width` and `height` and has its dimensions described in another way (e.g. a `<circle>`, whose width and height are determined by its radius attribute `r`) then the `<use>` element **will** display, but its `width` and `height` attributes are then ignored. The radius value is used instead.

In any case, if I wrap a rect definition (with no width or height attributes) in a `symbol`, and inherit that, again, the `<use>` element (with width and height set) fails to appear.

Seems like width and height on `<use>` elements don't really work according to SVG 1.1 spec. Apparently if you don't set a width and height on the referenced element, it defaults to auto (i.e. zero), and I suppose setting the width and height afterwards is just scaling something with zero dimensions or something?

Here's a small example which shows the problem (tested on Chrome, FF, Safari and Edge).

```css
/*selects a rect def*/
#rc {
 width:24px;
 height:24px;
}
/*selects a use instance*/
#u4 {
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="320px" height="240px" viewBox="0 0 320 240">
 <defs>
  <rect id="ra" width="20" height="10"/> <!-- width and height set in def -->
  <rect id="rb" /> <!-- width and height omitted in def -->
  <rect id="rc" /> <!-- width and height omitted in def -->
  <rect id="rd" /> <!-- width and height omitted in def -->
  <!-- defs wrapped in symbols -->
  <symbol id="re" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><rect /></symbol>
  <symbol id="cdef" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" /> 
  </symbol>
 </defs>
 
 <!-- using a def which includes width/height attributes (works) -->
 <use href="#ra" id="u1" x="10" y="10" fill="pink"/>
 
 <!-- setting width/height on use element (fails to display anything, but should work according to spec) -->
 <use href="#rb" id="u2" x="30" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="cyan" />
 
 <!-- setting width/height of def in css (works) -->
 <use href="#rc" id="u3" x="50" y="10" fill="slategray"/>
 
 <!-- setting width/height of use in css (does fail, according to spec)-->
 <use href="#rd" id="u4" x="50" y="10" fill="orange"/>
 
 <!-- setting width/height of use, inheriting from symbol rather than a rect directly-->
 <use href="#re" id="u4" x="60" y="20" width="20" height="20" fill="lime"/>
 
 <!-- inheriting from a circle (which has no width/height attributes) instead of a rect-->
 <use href="#cdef" id="u5" x="120" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="blue" />
 
 <!-- finally a plain old rect (for comparison) -->
 <rect id="r1" x="150" y="10" width="32" height="24" stroke="black" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

You'll notice that the **orange** element is not drawn, which is as expected: According to the spec, CSS rules can not be applied to `<use>` elements, only to the elements they inherit from. This is ok.

But the **cyan** element is not drawn either, even though it has a width and height attribute set. The only way I can get it to appear is to add a width and height to the `<def>`, which means the width and height attributes on the `<use>` element will be ignored, and which defeats the object of the exercise entirely.

Maybe someone can explain how setting `width`/`height` on `<use>` is supposed to work, or confirm that it is a bug (on all browsers!?)

Comment: you can set the width and height when you are using a symbol or a nested svg element with a viewBox attribute

Comment: hmm.. apparently not! I just added a viewbox to the symbol containing a rect (lime fill) and it still fails to show up.

Comment: a rect without width and/or height is not a rect

Comment: ...and width and height are ignored on <use> if the inherited rect has width and height set. This is exactly the problem.

Comment: That's not a problem, that's how it's supposed to work, which is why all browsers work the same way. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want a rect that I can <use> multiple times with different widths and heights. Ultimately the rect definition will have other properties that I also want to inherit, but I have omitted those here to focus on the width/height issue.

Comment: Maybe there's another way to achieve the same result though, in which case, I'd be delighted to learn about it!

Comment: <use> is not really the way to go then. Just create the elements you want directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. As I feared, it is apparently not possible.

Width and height attributes on `<use>` elements which reference a rect are simply ignored because

> The width and height attributes only have an effect if the referenced
>   element defines a viewport

(source:https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)

Update: A viable result with may be achieved by using CSS properties (also width and height) directly on elements without viewports. This will not distort stroke-width, rx, ry etc. and has excellent support across modern browsers at time of writing.

Comment: width and height are documented in the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width). It says there that such properties are not inherited and are therefore reset properties.

Comment: Yes, although my main focus here is not on CSS, but on SVG attributes.

Comment: But those "attributes" you're talking about are CSS.

Comment: They aren't yet! SVG 2.0 will expose these as CSS properties, but I don't think there are any implementations which do so in current browsers, which are still stuck with some variant of SVG 1.1

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari [all implement this](https://wpt.fyi/results/svg/geometry/reftests?label=master&label=experimental&aligned).

Comment: OK, that's interesting and very useful. I also notice that changing the width/height by css will not distort the stroke width (as transform will do). But I notice that the rect examples do not have width and height attributes in the markup. @enxaneta said that such a rect is not really a rect, and yet here it is working fine with CSS. So why can't we do the same trick with a <use> element? That's what continues to puzzle me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215297/discussion-between-brennanyoung-and-robert-longson).